# How to write this json data in array form

Tags: php

```
{
    "phone_number": "918358808742",
    "confirmation_token": "c86798c29bd811e58f5822000b9964d9",
    "experiment_data": {
        "opt_in_consent": 7,
        "conf_code_auto_submit_ff": 1,
        "manual_referral_code_switch": 1,
        "conf_code_auto_submit": 1,
        "registration_reminders": 1,
        "reengagement_gcm_switch": 1,
        "kraken_app_progress_meter_v2": 1,
        "kraken_background_service_control": 1,
        "modified_sms_confirmation_page": 1,
        "auto_sms_confirmation": 1,
        "registration_express": 1,
        "tutorial_before_offer_start": 1,
        "fb_connect_active": 1,
        "fb_connect_required_for_login": 1,
        "auto_sms_confirmation_v2": 1,
        "pwd_input_variations": 4,
        "registration_reminder_notifications": 1,
        "track_adwords_install": 1
    },
    "member_id": "a2mx2z"
}
```

I want this data to be in array form any help will be appreciated

Comment: Use php's build in `json_encode($variable, true)` method.

Comment: kindly show me am noob at this pls

Comment: @Durgesh, you need to try first! If you dont know anything in php, you cant expect much help form Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function, here a simple exmple

```
$json = {};
$array = json_decode($json, true); // if you would like arrays
$object = json_decode($json); // if you would like object

echo $array['phone_number']; // array example
echo $object->phone_number; // object example
```

if you would like to test the validation of your json before decode it you can do it using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function

```
$json = {};

if(json_encode($json) == false) {
    die("incorrect json !");
} else {
    // do the decoding 
}
```

Comment: if i want to change phone_number value using variable in this data then how can it might be possible so that i can obtain desired json result.

Comment: after the decoding you can change and variable **$array['phone_number'] = 123**

Comment: Thanx Fahed Bro for your reply.

Comment: Could you vote if this answered you, so the others will find the answer easily